# The Video Sequencer connection with the Material Texture in Blender

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, video-sequence-editor, video

How I can connect the Video Sequencer to the material so that when I change the video in the Video Sequencer, it automatically changes the video texture of the material in the Viewport?
(without outer render)

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Maybe there is an add-on for this, but if not, i think a python script would be the way to go.